# Is virtual memory a good indicator for process memory utilisation?

Tags: c++, memory, process, virtual, benchmarking

QA team sent us a memory consumption reprot for our shoftware showing that virtual memory used by the process piked to more than than 600 MB under heavy load. so I have ran the same tests and found that's true, but the private working set is only half that amount (around 300 MB) which is relativly fine.

My question is, what matter most in this case? virtual memory? or private working set?

Comment: Which OS are you using?  See Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/131303/linux-how-to-measure-actual-memory-usage-of-an-application-or-process

Comment: @mark: Windows 7 64bits.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166502/how-much-memory-is-my-windows-app-really-using

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to interpret Windows Task Manager?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170654/how-to-interpret-windows-task-manager). To summarize, it sort of depends why you (or QA) care how much memory the software uses. It has allocated 600MB of address space (the "virtual memory"), of which 300MB is resident and non-shared (the "private working set"). The other 300MB is either shared, or in the page file, or else isn't backed by "real" memory at all. Someone should decide what (if anything) is troubling about those numbers, and that will tell you which number matters.

Comment: On Windows(by Mark Russinovich):

1: [Part1](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2011/WCL405)

2: [Part2](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2011/WCL406), and here is the tool [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984186/what-is-private-bytes-virtual-bytes-working-set